# c# Lookup for a value in Dictionary of Dictionary

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I am in process of implementing design where information is organized in following way:

- Multiple sources will feed us with multiple case information.
- Each source is identified by SourceID string and each case is idenfied by CaseID string.
- The information packet will be encapsulated as InfoObject.

I thought of coding it as:

```
// MasterDB :(0..m)SourceID -- 1..n ->  [CaseID, InfoObject]
//
private Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, InfoObject>> MasterDB;

Class InfoObject
{
    string user;
}
```

This way addition and removal becomes very easy as they use SourceID and CaseID as key.

However lookup is little special. I want to lookup for a particular user (which is embedded inside the InfoObject).

How should I reorganize such that things become little efficient both for lookup and addition/removal?

UPDATE:

I tried a different approach using LINQ

```
var targetList = from entry in MasterDB                          
                 from entrytarget in entry.Value
                      where (entrytarget.Value.user == username)
                      select entrytarget.Value;
```

Minor issue is that the returned list is a IEnumerable list. Not sure if I can make LINQ output some other way.

Comment: So your lookups for source and case are good with this, but you want user ALSO to be fast lookup?  Or is user the only important lookup speed?

Comment: Is InfoObject just a string and nothing else?

Comment: You say "I want to lookup for a particular user". What do you mean by that? You want to retrieve all the InfoObjects which user field is equal to a specific user?

Comment: @James: Lookup is only for User. If matched I need to get that InfoObject

Comment: Since the Dictionary of String and Dictionary is named MasterDB, does that mean it is an in-memory database? If so, why do you have to load the entire DB into memory?

Comment: @icemanind: InfoObject has many more fields

Comment: How many records are we talking about?

Comment: @Tipx: Just the first match is good enough for now

Comment: @ceonikka: If you only ever look up by user, why have the dictionary indexed by case and source?  Just to maintain hierarchy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could just have a separate lookup for users:

```
Dictionary<string, InfoObject> userLookup;
```

This only of course if you want to optimize for lookup speed, the downside is that addition and removal you have to do now on two separate data structures which have to keep in sync.

Comment: Agreed, would just need to do some careful locking to make sure you remove them together so you don't get out of sync...

Comment: @James: Well, one must have a common mutex for the whole data structure.

Comment: How would that work? For eg. if I want to check if user "steve@something" exists in database. If yes, get the InfoObject.

Comment: @ceonikka: On every insertion of an `InfoObject` you would also have to populate the user lookup by adding `userLookup[someUser]= someInfoObject;`

Comment: I tried a different approach using LINQ

    var targetList = from entry in MasterDB                          
                     from entrytarget in entry.Value
                          where (entrytarget.Value.user == username)
                          select entrytarget.Value;

Minor issue is that the returned list is a IEnumerable list. Not sure if I can make LINQ output some other way.

Answer (score 3):

I would propose to maintain additionally another dictionary, mapping the `user` into the appropriate collection of all relevant `SourceID`/`CaseID` pairs.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a `Dictionary<string, IList<InfoObject>` since nothing guarantees a user can't have more than one SourceID/CaseID pair.

Whenever you insert something in your other dictionary, you also insert the same `InfoObject`s in that dictionary of IList. This way the `InfoObject` retrieved is the same object.

Comment: This is basically the same thing @Vlad said :-P